# Alternative factorization of $\prod\limits^{n}_{k=1}k!^{k+1}$

Tags: summation, factorial, products

***Question: How can I succinctly express (using the product and sum notations) the following expression?*** $$n^{(n+1)}(n-1)^{(n+1)+n}(n-2)^{(n+1)+n+(n-1)}\cdot\cdot\cdot 1^{(n+1)+n+(n-1)+\cdot\cdot\cdot+2}$$

---

Fun fact: The following is in fact alternatively expressible as:  $$\prod^{n}_{k=1}k!^{k+1}=\prod^{n}_{k=1}sf(k)H(k) \hspace{1mm}\rightarrow \hspace{3mm}sf(k)=\prod^{k}_{i=1}i!\hspace{1mm};H(k)=\prod^{k}_{i=1}i^i$$

---

EDIT: I think I got it: The given expression equals:$$\prod^{n}_{k=1}k^{\sum^{(n+1)}_{i=1}-\sum^{k}_{i=1}}=\prod^{n}_{k=1}k^{\frac{1}{2}[(n+1)(n+2)-k(k+1)]}$$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It seems to work just fine. The expression as well as the answer I've found both lead to the same answer for n=3: $3^4 \cdot 2^7 \cdot 1^9$. The $\prod^{3}_{k=1}k!^{k+1}=(1^2)(1^3)(2^3)(1^4)(2^4)(3^4)=1^9 \cdot 2^7 \cdot 3^4$ also yields the same.

Comment: I am sorry ! I had a typo. Your formula is perfect !! I shall delete my first and stupid comment. In fact, it is a very interesting and smart solution. $+1$ then.

Comment: You are welcome ! Again, this is nice work and I apologize for my stupid mistake and comment which were due to a typo on my side. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your representation is nice and correct. Here is a derivation

> \begin{align*}
> \prod_{k=1}^n{k!}^{k+1}&=\prod_{k=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^kj^{k+1}\\
> &=\prod_{j=1}^n\prod_{k=j}^{n}j^{k+1}\tag{1}\\
> &=\prod_{j=1}^n{j}^{\sum_{k=j}^n(k+1)}\\
> &=\prod_{j=1}^n{j}^{\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-\frac{(j-1)j}{2}\right)+\left(n-(j-1)\right)}\\
> &=\prod_{j=1}^nj^{\frac{1}{2}[(n+1)(n+2)-j(j+1)]}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we exchange the products. Note, the index range is $1\leq j\leq k\leq n$.